# Need help with Walker_Nav_Menu class

Tags: menus, walker

I am trying to learn how to use walker_nav_menu for past week but can't find the right material.
WP documentation just cover simple definition of walker nav menu class.
And most of the resources i found are not really working or outdated.

My walker class:

```
class WP_Bootstrap extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

  public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
   $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth);
   $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu$submenu depth_$depth\">\n"; 
 }

  public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

 }
}
```

My wp nav menu:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
            'theme_location' => 'top',
            'container' => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id' => 'navbarNav',
            'menu_class'   => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
            'walker' => new Wp_Bootstrap(),
        ) );
```

Why it's not working? i can't really see the output.
I also want to change class of li.

Comment: What output are you expecting, and what output are you getting. Note that your `start_el` method is empty, so no links are going to be output.

Comment: @JacobPeattie i just want to change li class name inside ul. I am bit confused what is the right method to put that logic in.